# asp.net image handler (.ashx) not showing images on SSL (https)

Tags: asp.net, imagehandler

I have image handler working fine on HTTP. But The same page when access using https its not showing up the image. When check browser console for errors its showing "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE".

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Do you have valid SSL certificate?

Comment: yes valid SSL certificate

Comment: When you are calling that ashx, are you specifying https or http? What exactly is the rendered html of that image tag?

Comment: I am specifying as https and it is rendering bytes which when assign to src of a image tag displaying as image.

Comment: @siddu The URL from which you are accessing and ashx file are in same domain or they are in different domains ?

Comment: The issue was fixed. Actually the problem is SSL configuration. It is working fine without www.. I fixed it. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when you try to load content from http site into https site. This results into Mixed-Content error.

On http page you can load contents from http or https both but when you are on https site then you can load contents like images or iframe only from https sites.

In this case i assume that the site which is sending request is on https but your ashx page is on http site.